# How to input a caret trained random forest model into predict() and performance() functions?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, predict, precision-recall

I want to create a precision recall curve using `performance()` but I don't know how to input my data. I follow this example.

```
attach(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction(ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
perf <- performance(pred,"prec","rec")
plot(perf)
```

I am trying to mimic that for my `caret` trained RF model ***specifically*** on training data (I know there are various examples on how to use `predict` on `newdata`). I tried this:

```
pred <- prediction(rf_train_model$pred$case, rf_train_model$pred$pred)
perf <- performance(pred,"prec","rec")
plot(perf)
```

My model below. I tried the above because that seems to match the `ROCR.simple` data.

```
#create model
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 5,
                     savePredictions = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs = TRUE)
set.seed(3949)
rf_train_model <- train(outcome ~ ., data=df_train, 
                  method= "rf",
                  ntree = 1500, 
                  tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 33), 
                  trControl = ctrl, 
                  preProc=c("center","scale"), 
                  metric="ROC",
                  importance=TRUE)

> head(rf_train_model$pred)
     pred     obs      case   control rowIndex mtry Resample
1 control control 0.3173333 0.6826667        4   33    Fold1
2 control control 0.3666667 0.6333333        7   33    Fold1
3 control control 0.2653333 0.7346667       16   33    Fold1
4 control control 0.1606667 0.8393333       18   33    Fold1
5 control control 0.2840000 0.7160000       20   33    Fold1
6    case    case 0.6206667 0.3793333       25   33    Fold1
```

This is wrong because my precision recall curve is going the wrong way. I am interested in more than just the PRAUC curve, although this is a [good source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/calculating-aupr-in-r) that shows how to make it so I would like to fix this error. What error am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the vignette of performance:

> it has to be declared which class label denotes the negative, and
>   which the positive class. Ideally, labels should be supplied as
>   ordered factor(s), the lower level corresponding to the negative
>   class, the upper level to the positive class. If the labels are
>   factors (unordered), numeric, logical or characters, ordering of the
>   labels is inferred from R's built-in < relation (e.g. 0 < 1, -1 < 1,
>   'a' < 'b', FALSE < TRUE).

In your case, when you provide rf_train_model$pred$pred, the upper level is still "control", so the best way is to make it TRUE / FALSE. Also you should provide the actual label, not the predicted label, `rf_train_model$obs`. see below for an example:

```
library(caret)
library(ROCR)
set.seed(100)
df = data.frame(matrix(runif(100*100),ncol=100))
df$outcome = ifelse(runif(100)>0.5,"case","control")

df_train = df[1:80,]
df_test = df[81:100,]

rf_train_model <- train(outcome ~ ., data=df_train, 
                  method= "rf",
                  ntree = 1500, 
                  tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 33), 
                  trControl = ctrl, 
                  preProc=c("center","scale"), 
                  metric="ROC",
                  importance=TRUE)

levels(rf_train_model$pred$pred)
[1] "case"    "control"

plotCurve = function(label,positive_class,prob){
pred = prediction(prob,label==positive_class)
perf <- performance(pred,"prec","rec")
plot(perf)
}

plotCurve(rf_train_model$pred$obs,"case",rf_train_model$pred$case)
plotCurve(rf_test$outcome,"case",predict(rf_train,df_test,type="prob")[,2])
```

Comment: thank you thank you so much! I've been trying to understand this for a while! Also it was helpful you added it for `df_test` because that would've been my follow up question. One point of clarification. Correct me if I'm wrong but the information in `rf_train_model$pred` represents the probabilities of the five different testing folds from `df_train`. Is it possible to access the probabilities of the five training probabilities from `df_train`. I'm asking in the context of now also wanting PRAUC curves for the training sets in addition to the testing sets from `df_train` and `df_test`

Comment: Yes it is the test fold. I don't think it's possible within caret to get the training values back. You might have to implement it yourself.

Comment: you mean using `randomForest()` basically?

Comment: yeah, you can use createFolds from caret to create the folds.

Comment: excellent! and sorry one last question (please tell me if this is off-topic, a lot of these concepts are related in my head). Does `caret` give the probabilities of the entire trained model on `df_train` or would I have to have to generate that model separately? I guess thinking along the lines of creating an ROC/AUPRC curve for the entire training data instead of what's observes in each of the folds. I believe it's `model$votes` and I essentially follow this method here?

Comment: yes, when you do predict(<caret model>, type="prob") it gives you the probabilities from the final model, trained on all of df_train